# documentModel.getProperty returns Integer instead of Long after upgrading to Nuxeo 7.10

Tags: java, nuxeo

When I try to retrieve a property from my DocumentModel, using the `getProperty(String schemaName, String name)` method, I get the property as an `Integer` Java object instead of a `Long` Java Object, however Nuxeo is supposed to provide a Long object as shown [here](https://doc.nuxeo.com/display/NXDOC710/Schema+Fields).

The field I'm having trouble to get is actually defined as an auto-incremented idfield in the directory.

This used to work just fine in 5.8 but after the upgrade it's not working anymore, what could be the reason of this disfunction ?

## EDIT

In my schema the field is defined as the following :

```
<xs:element name="myid" type="xs:integer" />
```

In my database it's defined as :

```
"myid" NUMBER (19) ;
```

And I have a constraint on the id

```
ADD CONSTRAINT MYID_PK PRIMARY KEY ( "myid" )
```

When I try the following

```
documentModel.getProperty("myTableSchema", "myid");
```

The return value is correct but the type is an `Integer`!

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts from `nuxeoctl showconf`

Comment: @JulienCarsique, I think that the conf part that might be related this, is the fact that I'm starting from an existing database.

Comment: I mean: did you applied some hotfixes, which templates and packages, which database..?

Comment: No I didn't apply any hotfixes, I'm using Oracle database, and my project is a plugin to Nuxeo, are there any other piece of information that you want me to share ?

Comment: What specific property are you having a problem with, and how is the it defined in its Nuxeo schema and what is the corresponding column definition in the database.